# How to group powershell select-string output based on filename

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I'm using the following Powershell command... not an expert at all, so willing to try different ways.

```
    select-string -path *.html -pattern $pattern -allmatches |
foreach-object {write-host $_.filename; $_.matches} | 
foreach-object {$_.groups[1].value}
```

I would like to group all of the matches belonging to a file like

```
filename.html
  match
  match
filename2.html
  match
```

and so on...

Can I do this using the approach above, if so, how? If not, could you suggest a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the list of commands below to group the files with the extensions in a folder

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "Source Directory Path"-Recurse
$files | Group-Object -Property Extension
write-host $files
```

[image: Output]